# Hiding Dropdown "caret" when sticky header is present

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

So right now I'm building out our new website, and I've programmed a nice little sticky header using javascript. Here's my Javascript.

http://dev.yoursparksource.com

```
<script>
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){  
    $('.stickyheader1').addClass("sticky");
}
else{
    $('.stickyheader1').removeClass("sticky");
}
});
</script>
```

And my CSS for the stickyheader and .sticky added class

```
.stickyheader1 {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
-webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
height: 85px;
}

.stickyheader1.sticky {
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.80);
-webkit-transition: background .4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: background .4s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: background .4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: background .4s ease-in-out;
transition: background .4s ease-in-out;
}
```

And this works PERFECT. My problem is the dropdown menu. I styled a little CSS caret, and when you scroll down and the header background activates, the caret is on top of the header's space, and you can see it behind the semi-transperent header. (EWW! Tacky...)

What I'm wondering, is how can I target this element, as it's an :after pseudo class.. Here's the current CSS for the caret (or top triangle as some call it.)

```
#nav ul ul:After {
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 10px 10px;
border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.40) transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
top: -10px;
left: 20px;
}
```

I tried just using the same javascript with the "#nav ul ul:After", but after researching, I learned how you can't add styles to a pseudo class. Duh, I knew that, just forgot. That's all. ;-) Any assistance on getting that little caret to go away when I scroll and the stick header's bg activates? Would be a lifesaver for me. (Also, if it can animate with the opacity transition like the header, that would rock. Once I figure out how to target it, I can add the css animation.

Thanks a MILLION in advance! I love StackOverflow.

Comment: You should clean up your code by 75% first as `transition` is no longer prefixed in [any browser currently in widespread use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions).

Comment: I think I'd put the caret in a span first, then you can reference it better! Can we see the html for the elements around the caret.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes thanks for that heads up haha, I wasn't aware! I have a lot of code to clean. :) Seems like it works back to IE 8 too which is awesome!

Comment: @ShowcaseImagery I tried putting it in a span and I couldn't get it to show up at all. Maybe because it needs relative positioning at that point? Hmm. Would I wrap that span around the sub nav's <ul> or put it before it?

Comment: @MarkCuda actually IE8/9 don't support transitions at all, and IE10+ don't need a prefix. `-ms-transition` has never existed. See the table I linked (red = no support).

Answer (score 0):

You will need JavaScript to loop through the stylesheet, find the rule for `#nav ul ul:After` and set its `display` property to `none` after the `sticky` class is added to `.stickyheader1`.

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
    $('.stickyheader1').addClass("sticky");
    var ss = document.styleSheets;
    for (i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
      var rules = ss[i];
      for (j = 0; j < rules.cssRules.length; j++) {
        var r = rules.cssRules[j];
        if (r.selectorText == "#nav ul ul:After" || r.selectorText == "#nav ul ul::After") {
          r.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    $('.stickyheader1').removeClass("sticky");
  }
});
```

Comment: Tried this code, didn't work :/ I made sure the selector was exactly what the other one was, as you saw in the code. Thanks in advance for your help, really do appreacite this community.

Comment: @MarkCuda - Did you check the console for any errors?

Comment: @MarkCuda - I've updated the code, it should work now. I'm guessing that you are on Chrome and Chrome doesn't automatically convert `:after` to its standard notation(`::after`) while Firefox does. I've added an `or`(`||`) statement for that.

Comment: I'm really sorry for the late reply, but thanks a million, that really helped out.